# Update MongoDB documents into a geometry

Tags: database, mongodb, geometry

I'm really new into MongoDB and I am trying to update an already existing collection. The collection has some documents that have the field longitude and latitude. The documents look like this:

```json
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63d19f661991a09011e4d8ab"),
    sourcemmsi: 111224102,
    altitude: 1499,
    relative_to_ground: { speedoverground: 160, courseoverground: 293.7 },
    coordinates: {
      longitude: -8.536587,
      latitude: 45.494465,
      timestamp: 1443898700
    }
  }
```

What I am really trying is to use the `$geometry` operation so I can have a new field **type:Point** and **coordinates : [long, lat]** without the timestamp. Is there any way possible to achieve that?

Comment: To update the documnets, you will need `update` and `$set`, what are you trying to do with `$geometry`?

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wFThEX2ne13) that creates a new field, `"location"` that holds a [GeoJSON Object](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/#point)?